# how to make paypal mass payment in android app

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am making android app in which I have to integrate paypal integration.But requirement is that i have **to make mass payment using paypal i.e. multiple recipients at time**.
I have gone though this [paypal_mpl](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_android.pdf) and [paypal_mecl](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_mecl_developer_guide_and_reference_android.pdf).

[This blog](http://mukeshyadav4u.blogspot.in/2012/09/paypal-integration-in-android.html) has given clear idea about **parallel payment**.

Now my question is that, this is the only way that have to make mass payment or can I do it with other way in android?
Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no solution to do MassPay directly from an Android application. You would need to write a server side component to use PayPal's MassPay API. You can find out more about MassPay here: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mass-pay

Comment: Can u please explain me , what is the difference between **Parallel Payment** in MPL and **Mass Payment**?

Comment: Parallel Payment is a small batch of payments between one sender and upto 7 receivers in the same API call. It is built for multi-merchant marketplace kind of use cases.

MassPay is a full scale batch processing API that can process up to 250 recipients. It is built for back office processes/settlements.